# fill background image and href in javascripting

Tags: javascript, html

I have online inserted background-image in div tag so and i want that
image automatically get copy background-image value in `href=""` tag.

HTML Code

```
<a href="" class="over">
    <div class="fill" style="background-image:url(images/9XkFhM8tRiuHXZRCKSdm_ny-2.jpg);"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do elaborate your scenario to get a perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will add url of image to the href of its `a` tag. Use it as you wish.

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.fill');
for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i += 1) {
    var style = elems[i].style.backgroundImage;
    var url = style.substring(4, style.length-1);
    elems[i].parentNode.href = url
};
```

Check it in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjxqtuzh/).

Comment: thank you sir your code is working but your code create a src="" tag in div but i want to create background image url in href="" tag.....

Comment: Check the fiddle I've added in the answer. It doesn't create any src attr